# How to get the last file in an array

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code to download a file in the database, but it only downloads the first user upload.
I tried using LastOrDefault and reverse to download the most recent file but I couldn't.
Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/DownloadFileCNPJ/{Id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFileCNPJ(long Id)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var cartaoCnpj = (from j in context.CartaoCNPJCedentes
                            where j.CedenteId.Equals(Id)
                            select j).Reverse().FirstOrDefault();

        if (cartaoCnpj != null)
        {
            var content = new System.IO.MemoryStream(cartaoCnpj.CartaoCNPJ);
            var contentType = cartaoCnpj.TipoCartãoCNPJ;
            var fileName = cartaoCnpj.NomeArquivoCNPJ;
            return File(content, contentType, fileName);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you would have to order by an upload date or timestamp. Without an order by clause you can't guarantee the sort order.

Comment: How are you defining "first" and "last"? Seems like you should order by that field.

Comment: First you do a reverse without sorting your database query. Return from some database engine are random and do not ensure same order for the same query unless an order by is enforced